# Is there a closed form for the recurrence $V_{n+1}={V_n+\Delta V\over 1+{V_n\cdot \Delta V/C^2}}$, for constants $\Delta V$ and $C$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, special-relativity

I was wondering if the following recurrence formula has a closed form:

> $$V_{n+1}={V_n+\Delta V\over 1+{V_n\cdot \Delta V\over C^2}}$$

where $\Delta V$ and $C$ are positive constants, $V_n$ is the velocity of the $n$-the inertial frame and the primary velocity $V_0$ is given (take it $0$ if needed).

**Attempt**

This sequence obviously tends to $C$ (the speed-of-light supremum of speeds of observations), so I naturally tried to crack it using $$e_n=V_n-C$$but I failed. Any idea is appreciated.

**Note**

The above rule determines the [Relativistic Velocity-addition Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) where $V_n$ is supposed to be the velocity of the inertial frame $2$ that is moving with respect to us (inertial frame $1$) and $\Delta V$ is an increase in the speed of the moving object (or we can assume it as the relative speed of object in the inertial frame 2). My work basis is the [Lorentz Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).

Comment: The link is breaking but you need the whole link, i dont know why its not including the rest in my comment above, so heres another link you can try if you can't get the one above to work [here](https://bit.ly/2OpuHh6)

Comment: It breaks on asterisk.

Comment: Try my latest link, i removed my old comment

Comment: Thank you for the link and the final answer. Can you also give me the details for the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately for that I can't, because (1) I know nothing about relativity and (2) I don't even know how to arrive to the closed form Wolfram gives. I assume you know the value of $V_1$ and $V_2$ to determine the arbitrary constant given in the closed form. Hopefully atleast knowing the closed form can lead you to the details. I will try a bit more to see how Wolfram is generating it

Comment: The Mathematica code generating the solution is RSolve[a[1 + n] == (k + a[n])/(1 + (k a[n])/c^2), {a[n]}, n

Comment: Oh. I don't have Mathematica :)

Comment: Neither do I, I just got the code from the same link as before. That was just incase you did and would find it useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining $U_n := V_n/C$ and $D := \Delta V/C$, we can write the simpler-looking recurrence
$$U_{n+1} = \frac{D + U_n}{1 + D\,U_n} \tag{1}$$
which bears a resemblance to the angle-addition formula for hyperbolic tangent:
$$\tanh(a+b) = \frac{\tanh a + \tanh b}{1 + \tanh a\,\tanh b} \tag{2}$$
Thus, if we further define $u_n := \operatorname{arctanh U_n}$ and $d := \operatorname{arctanh D}$, then we have
$$\tanh u_{n+1} = U_{n+1} = \frac{D+U_n}{1+D\,U_n} = \frac{\tanh d + \tanh u_n}{1 + \tanh d\tanh u_n} = \tanh(d+u_n) \tag{3}$$
so that $u_{n+1} = d + u_n$. Consequently, taking $V_0 = U_0 = u_0 = 0$, we have $u_n = n d$, which gives

> $$V_n= C\,\tanh\left( n \operatorname{arctanh}\frac{\Delta V}{C} \right) \tag{$\star$}$$

As $n$ grows without bound (with $\Delta V/C > 0$), the $\tanh$ factor approaches $1$, so that $V_n$ approaches $C$ (as OP has observed).

---

Using the exponential definition of $\tanh$, we can re-write $(\star)$ as
$$V_n = C \frac{e^{nd}-e^{-nd}}{e^{nd}+e^{-nd}} = C\frac{\left(e^d\right)^n-\left(e^d\right)^{-n}}{\left(e^d\right)^n+\left(e^d\right)^{-n}} \tag{4}$$
Note that 
$$e^d = \exp \operatorname{arctanh} D = \exp \left(\frac12\,\log\frac{1+D}{1-D}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1+D}{1-D}} \tag{5}$$
Substituting $(5)$ into $(4)$ and simplifying ultimately gives

> $$V_n = C\frac{(1+D)^n-(1-D)^n}{(1+D)^n+(1-D)^n} = C\frac{(C+\Delta V)^n-(C-\Delta V)^n}{(C+\Delta V)^n + (C-\Delta V)^n} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

which agrees with [@Hushus46's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3159334/409).

Answer (score 2):

As I have noted in the comment, [Wolfram Alpha](https://bit.ly/2OpuHh6) gives the closed form, with $k = \Delta V$:

$$V_n = \frac{C_1 c(c+k) \left( \frac{1}{k-c} + \frac{1}{c}\right)^n - c(c-k)\left(-\frac{k}{c(c+k)}\right)^n}{(c-k)\left(-\frac{k}{c(c+k)}\right)^n + C_1 (c+k) \left(\frac{1}{k-c}+\frac{1}{c}\right)^n}$$

Taking $V_0 = 0$, we can see

$$ 0 = \frac{C_1 c(c+k)  - c(c-k)}{(c-k) + C_1 (c+k) }$$

which is undefined if $C_1 = -\frac{c-k}{c+k}$, so let $C_1 \ne -\frac{c-k}{c+k}$, then

$$0 = C_1 c(c+k)-c(c-k)\Rightarrow 0 = C_1(c+k)-c+k \Rightarrow C_1=\frac{c-k}{c+k}$$

Hence $C_1$ is undefined when $k = \Delta V = -C$, so depending on the physical context of special realtivity (which I don't know enough of), this may never happen

Substituting this into the original closed form:
\begin{align}V_n &= \frac{(\frac{c-k}{c+k}) c(c+k) \left( \frac{1}{k-c} + \frac{1}{c}\right)^n - c(c-k)\left(-\frac{k}{c(c+k)}\right)^n}{(c-k)\left(-\frac{k}{c(c+k)}\right)^n + (\frac{c-k}{c+k}) (c+k) \left(\frac{1}{k-c}+\frac{1}{c}\right)^n} \\
&=\frac{c(c-k)\left[ \left( \frac{1}{k-c} + \frac{1}{c}\right)^n - \left(-\frac{k}{c(c+k)}\right)^n\right]}{(c-k)\left[\left(-\frac{k}{c(c+k)}\right)^n +   \left(\frac{1}{k-c}+\frac{1}{c}\right)^n\right]}\\
&= c \frac{\left[ \left( \frac{1}{k-c} + \frac{1}{c}\right)^n - \left(-\frac{k}{c(c+k)}\right)^n\right]}{\left[\left(-\frac{k}{c(c+k)}\right)^n +   \left(\frac{1}{k-c}+\frac{1}{c}\right)^n\right]}\end{align}

Hence in terms of the way you formulated you have

$$ \boxed{V_n=C \frac{\left[ \left( \frac{1}{\Delta V-C} + \frac{1}{C}\right)^n - \left(-\frac{\Delta V}{C(C+\Delta V)}\right)^n\right]}{\left[\left(-\frac{\Delta V}{C(C+\Delta V)}\right)^n +   \left(\frac{1}{\Delta V-C}+\frac{1}{C}\right)^n\right]} \quad \Delta V \ne \pm C ,\, C \ne 0}$$

if one wishes a preferable altenartive form without negatives inside the power terms:

\begin{align}V_n&=C \frac{\left[ \left( \frac{\Delta V}{C(\Delta V - C)}\right)^n - \left(-\frac{\Delta V}{C(C+\Delta V)}\right)^n\right]}{\left[\left(-\frac{\Delta V}{C(C+\Delta V)}\right)^n +   \left(\frac{\Delta V}{C(\Delta V - C)}\right)^n\right]} \\
&=C \frac{\left[ \left( -\frac{\Delta V}{C(C-\Delta V)}\right)^n - \left(-\frac{\Delta V}{C(C+\Delta V)}\right)^n\right]}{\left[\left(-\frac{\Delta V}{C(C+\Delta V)}\right)^n +   \left(-\frac{\Delta V}{C(C- \Delta V)}\right)^n\right]} \\
&=C \frac{\left[ (-1)^n \left(\frac{\Delta V}{C}\right)^n\left( \frac{1}{(C-\Delta V)}\right)^n - (-1)^n \left(\frac{\Delta V}{C}\right)^n \left(\frac{1}{(C+\Delta V)}\right)^n\right]}{\left[(-1)^n \left(\frac{\Delta V}{C}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{(C+\Delta V)}\right)^n +   (-1)^n \left(\frac{\Delta V}{C}\right)^n \left(\frac{1}{(C- \Delta V)}\right)^n\right]} \end{align}
which is written
\begin{align}V_n&=C \frac{\left[ \left( \frac{1}{C-\Delta V}\right)^n - \left(\frac{1}{C+\Delta V}\right)^n\right]}{\left[\left( \frac{1}{C-\Delta V}\right)^n + \left(\frac{1}{C+\Delta V}\right)^n\right]} \\
&=C \frac{\left[ \left( \frac{1}{C-\Delta V}\right)^n - \left(\frac{1}{C+\Delta V}\right)^n\right]}{\left[\left( \frac{1}{C-\Delta V}\right)^n + \left(\frac{1}{C+\Delta V}\right)^n\right]} \frac{(C+\Delta V)^n (C-\Delta V)^n}{(C+\Delta V)^n (C-\Delta V)^n}\end{align} 
Finally,
$$\boxed{V_n=C \frac{\left[ \left( C+\Delta V\right)^n - \left(C- \Delta V\right)^n\right]}{\left[\left( C+ \Delta V\right)^n + \left(C- \Delta V\right)^n\right]} \quad \Delta V \ne \pm C ,\, C \ne 0}$$

which is in the form:

$$V_n = C \frac{a^n-b^n}{a^n+b^n}$$

which has limit $C$ as $n \to \infty $ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531193/help-thorougly-proving-a-limit-ab0-an-bn-anbn-as-n-to-infty) if you don't know how to show that), matching the limit in the OP's question.

**If anyone knows how to derive the solution Wolfram gets, that would be preferable to this**

Comment: Note that you can factor-out $(\Delta V/C)^n$ from the numerator and denominator of your "preferable alternative form". Then, multiplying numerator and denominator by $(C-\Delta V)^n (C+\Delta V)^n$ simplifies things further.

Comment: @Blue Good point, I'll edit that in

Comment: @Blue Didn't see your edited comment, will add those changes as well. Thanks for the help